# HTML5 Audio Won't Load Using Safari for Mavericks

Tags: safari, osx-mavericks, html5-audio

Here is the code I am using for the audio:

```
<audio controls preload="none" class="voice-audio">
    <source class="voice-audio-source" src="<path to content>")" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <p>Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.</p>
</audio>
```

The audio will not load at all on Safari for Mavericks. Has anyone successfully done this?

Comment: Is it working on firefox?

Comment: I do not have a mac but someone assisting me with the testing has let me know that it works everywhere BUT Safari for Mavericks. That's the only browser where the audio is getting hung up. I'm on a pc and it works in all browsers for me, even Safari for Windows.

Comment: Not sure it will help but it probably the safari fault https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5506319?tstart=0

Comment: thanks. saw those and still looking into.

Comment: I am closing because I am hoping it will be solved with the use of jPlayer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jPlayer in the hopes of resolving.